# How to mix c and c++ form application in the same project?

Tags: c, winforms, visual-c++

I want a program that C program with a C++ form application using together in the same project.

for example:

1. When I clicked a button send entered text to C program. entered text to inside textBox in a C++ form app.
2. C program will save the text to computer with file operations.

so simply example:

```
textBox1="hello world"
button=clicked
string^ message = textBox->Text;
writerFunction(message);


void writerFunction(char m[50])
{
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("text.txt","a");
  fprintf(fp,"%s",m);
  fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: You can use C functions in your C++ program. There's no need to write two programs.

Comment: in c++ Windows Form Application program ??

Comment: C++ is backward compatible with C

Comment: For example: I can't use "FILE" in c++ form apps

Comment: Looks like XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Ask how to use FILE* in C++/CLI program, instead of strange two-projects idea. Or better, use .NET IO namespace classes instead of FILE*. Or even better - go to C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using C++ .NET (managed c++)
I'm guessing this from pointer operator. In standard c++
you would use '*' instead of '^'.
Please correct my if I'm wrong there.

Two options.

- you are using managed c++ so you can call Win32 API but you will make your work harder. If you still intrested please check this link. It will get you started.
  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9714/Win-API-C-to-NET

But I'd suggest you to use c++ .NET approach to save the string in file. Google will find many examples for you.
One to start:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19czdak8.aspx

- if you want to use old style c++ you can mix c and c++ without any problems. You will need to import libs to your project.
  Libraries:

C
- stdio.h examples here (http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output)

C++
-ofstream: Stream class to write on files

-ifstream: Stream class to read from files

-fstream: Stream class to both read and write from/to files.

More details here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Windows API
- you can use win32 API by importing header
 Windows.h

Few examples here (http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/31282/windows-api-functions-to-read-and-write-files-in-c)

Good luck. If you need more info please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is just embed your C code in C++. It should work, unless any platform specific thing barrier you.

If you do need to have two (or more) programs and if they should run as two different processes in the OS, you should use a proper inter process communication technique. I know nothing about .Net stuff. However, you may use pipes, shared memory, memory mapped files and even sockets work too.

Or else, you can create a dynamic library based on C and call the function in your C++ form application.

Comment: yes, you are right i understood i will try to create a dynamic function.